# get value of checkbox submit to a variable

Tags: php, checkbox

I'm trying to work out how to get the value of a checkbox submit it to a variable which is an id from a sql db.

Below is my current code:

-- Index.php

```
<?php

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `file`";

      if (!$result = $db->query($sql)){
          die('There was an error running the query [' . $db->error . ']');
          }
    ?>

    <form method="post">

    <a href="includes/AED/file_add.php" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#NEW"><button class="btn btn-success">New</button></a>
    <a href="includes/AED/file_edit.php" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#EDIT"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning">Edit</button></a>
    <a href="includes/AED/file_delete.php" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#DELETE"><button class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button></a>

    <table class="table table-condensed">

      <thead>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Category</th>
        <th>Date</th>
      </thead>

      <tbody>

        <?php  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){ ?>

        <td><input type="checkbox" name="id_grab" value="<?php echo $row['file_id']; ?>"></td>
        <td><a href="simple/files/<?php echo $row['file_location']; ?>"><?php echo $row['file_name']; ?></a></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['file_category']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo date('d-m-y', strtotime($row['file_date'])); ?></td>

      </tbody>

    <?php } ?>
    </table>

    </form>
```

-- file_edit.php

```
<?php include('../db_connect.php') ;

$id=isset($_POST['id_grab']);

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `file` WHERE file_id = $id";

      if (!$result = $db->query($sql)){
          die('There was an error running the query [' . $db->error . ']');
          }

        $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
?>



<div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;       </button>
    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Edit Invoice / Receipt</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">

    <form action="../includes/file_update.php" method="post" role="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="File_Name">Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="file_name" class="form-control" id="file_name" value="<?php echo $row['file_name']; ?>">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <lable for="File_Category">Category</label>
            <input type="text" name="file_category" class="form-control" id="file_category" placeholder="Financial">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="file_tag">Tag</label>
            <input type="text" name="file_tag" class="form-control" id="file_tag" placeholder="statement">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="file_description">Description</label>
            <input type="text" name="file_description" class="form-control" id="file_description">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="file_date">Date</label>
            <input type="date" name="file_date" class="form-control" id="file_date">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="file_location">File</label>
            <input type="file" class="form-control" name="file_location" value="file">
            <p class="help-block">Select appropriate file for upload.</p>
        </div>

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Upload</button>


    </form>
</div>
```

I can't work it out, spent hours looking online... My concern is at it's using Bootstraps Modal I wasn't sure if it would be able to grat the POST data... As if I enter the ID manually it works...

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I suggest taking a smaller use case and putting it up on jsfiddle or something similar, its hard to follow your code and the question can be asked more clearly.

Comment: I take it you've already established a DB connection in `Index.php`

Comment: https://nas.tgcowell.com/simple

Comment: Yes, the db connection is working... Please refer to above link.

Answer (score 0):

change this

```
$id=isset($_POST['id_grab']);
```

to

```
$id=isset($_POST['id_grab'])?$_POST['id_grab']:'';
//if id_grab dont have a value then $id value will be ''
```

`isset()` Returns `TRUE` if var exists and has value other than `NULL`, `FALSE` otherwise.

Comment: I've tried the above, I'm now getting an error stating: There was an error running the query [You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1]

Comment: first try to print the `$id` value,i think you are not getting the value from `_POST['id_grab']`